# How to calculate the electrical force of attraction between a dipole and ion?

Tags: electrostatics, dipole

How would you calculate the electric force of attraction between a polar molecule, like carbon monoxide, and a positive ion with a magnitude of 1 if the distance between them were 0.1 m?

I know that the potential energy of interaction can be calculated using
$$U=-\frac{q\mu}{4\pi\epsilon_{0}r^{2}}.$$
I realize this is very similar to Coloumb's Law, the charge is replaced with the permanent dipole moment of a polar molecule. This causes the answer to be in joules instead of newtons, so how would I calculate the electric force?

Answer (score 1):

Here you have to take into account not only the distance, but also geometry (mutual positioning) of dipole and the charge. Also, the force won't be pure attraction or repulsion, but the superposition of attraction to one pole of dipole and repulsion from the other one, so net force will be "sideways", so to say.
When the distance is much greater than the geometric size of the dipole, you could use the following expression for a magnitude of electrical field:
$$E=\frac{1}{4\pi \varepsilon_{0}}\frac{\mu}{r^3}\sqrt{1+3\cos^2 \alpha},$$
where $\alpha$ is an angle between dipole axis and the position vector of the charge. So the force will be
$$F = qE = \frac{1}{4\pi \varepsilon_{0}}\frac{q \mu}{r^3}\sqrt{1+3\cos^2 \alpha}.$$